# Cannot resolve method getBaseContext()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement the slideshow function in my homeFragmement but I'm having an issues that says that my getBaseContext() can't be resolve? Why is this happening and how to solve this problem?

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        //slideshow
        flipperLayout= flipperLayout.findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        // add pics in drawable

        int imageDrawable[]={R.drawable.ba_banner,R.drawable.cala_banner,R.drawable.tp_banner};

        for (int i=0; i<imageDrawable.length;i++)
        {
            FlipperView flipperView= new FlipperView(getBaseContext());
            flipperView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable[i]);
            flipperLayout.addFlipperView(flipperView);

        }

    }
```

Comment: try getactivity().getBaseContext() or set context in constructor

Comment: the method getactivity().getBaseContext()  still got me an error "cannot resolve method". How to set context in constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are in Fragment and the method `getBaseContext()` is the Activity method, So you need to use it like:

```
getActivity().getBaseContext();
```

Even you call it with the context also in some scenarios like:

```
((context)Activity).getBaseContext();
```

Comment: i change the coding as u suggested into this ``` for (int i=0; i<imageDrawable.length;i++)
        {
            FlipperView flipperView=new FlipperView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            flipperView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable[i]);
            flipperLayout.addFlipperView(flipperView);

        } 
```

and have error on this line ```  flipperLayout= flipperLayout.findViewById(R.id.flipper); 
```
the error said " unreachable statement" may i know why and how to solve it? I'm new to fragment and I don't really know on how to use it.

Comment: Try an other thing.  Make context static in MainActivity and and in onCreate assign it context=this; and than try ((MainActivity.context)Activity).getBaseContext(); as its not good approach but maybe it will help you.